# Iterate through map values in dart / flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am basically from JS background and now trying my hands on flutter framework.
I am stuck in formatting my data I received from API.

Data Received an array of objects

```
 [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "name1",
     "type": "Both",
     "count": 4
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "name2",
     "type": "Both",
     "count": 6
   },
   {
     "id": 3,
     "name": "name1",
     "type": "Both",
     "count": 2
   },
   {
     "id": 4,
     "name": "name3",
     "type": "Both",
     "count": 8
   },
   ......
 ]
```

My Requirement is I will have to group the data based on the name

```
{
  name1: [
           {
             "id": 1, "name":"name1", "type": "Both", "count": 4
           },
           {
             "id": 3, "name":"name1", "type": "Both", "count": 2
           }
  ],
  name2: [
           {
             "id": 2, "name":"name2", "type": "Both", "count": 6
           }
  ],
  .....
}
```

In dart, I have managed to do that grouping using groupBy from collections.dart package.

The problem is I cannot loop through the grouped data. I need to access the count for some manipulation for each grouped name.

Below is the code snipped which I tried

```
  Map data;
  List partySnapData;
  Map newMap;

  Future _getTopParties() async {
   final response =await http.get(API_URL + '/getPartySnapShot');
   data =json.decode(response.body);
   partySnapData = data['resultObj'];
   setState(() {
    newMap = groupBy(partySnapData, (obj) => obj['party_name']);
    for(var v in newMap.values) {
     print(v);
    }
 });
```

}

The print(v) actually gave me the value mapped for the map E.G

```
[
  { "id": 1, "name":"name1", "type": "Both", "count": 4 },
  { "id": 3, "name":"name1", "type": "Both", "count": 2 }
],
.....,
......
```

Now, how do I loop or iterate through the array, here the **v**, so that i can access the elements inside?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found a solution to this. I am posting that, incase it helps someone.

I wanted to loop through the v to generate objects.

```
newMap = groupBy(partySnapData, (obj) => obj['party_name']);
for(var v in newMap.values) {
 print(v);
 //below is the solution
  v.asMap().forEach((i, value) {
    print('index=$i, value=$value');
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `groupBy()` is that something you wrote or its flutter method?

Comment: groupBy part of this references  https://pub.dev/packages/collection a third-party collection package.

Answer (score 22):

Ignoring your specific case but answering the question in case others come across this question like I did while searching for `How to iterate through map values in dart / flutter`.

There is a simpler and a better approach.

Here's the best approach (because this way you can `break` the `for loop` after finding the right entry and doing what you had to do to avoid unnecessary iterations).

```
for (MapEntry<type, type> item in myMap.entries) {
  //Here each item has a key and a value proterties.
  //Don't forget to use break; to end the loop when you are done and avoid unnecessary iterations.
}
```

And here is the easier:

```
myMap.forEach((key, value) {
  //Here you have key and value for each item in your map but you can't break the loop
  //to avoid unnecessary iterations.
  //This approach is only useful when you need to perform changes in all Map items.
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED**

```
List<Map> list = [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "name1",
         "type": "Both",
         "count": 4
       },
       {
         "id": 2,
         "name": "name2",
         "type": "Both",
         "count": 6
       },
       {
         "id": 3,
         "name": "name1",
         "type": "Both",
         "count": 2
       },
       {
         "id": 4,
         "name": "name3",
         "type": "Both",
         "count": 8
       }];
        Map sorted={};

      @override
      void initState(){
        super.initState();
        for(Map m in list){
          if(sorted[m['name'].toString()]==null)
            sorted[m['name'].toString()]=[];

          sorted[m['name'].toString()].add(m);

        }
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        body:Container(
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(20),
        color:Colors.white,
        alignment:Alignment.center,
        child:Column(
          mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Original\n $list',
                      style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
            SizedBox(height:15),
            Text('Sorted\n $sorted',
                      style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
//EDIT
            SizedBox(height:15),
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap:true,
              children: sorted.entries.map<Widget>((value){
                return Column(
                     mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
                     crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                     children:[

Text(value.key.toString(),style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black,
                                                     fontWeight:FontWeight.bold)),
            Column(
            mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
            children:value.value.map<Widget>((subValue){
              return Text(subValue['count'].toString(),style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black));
            }).toList(),
            ),
          ]
          );
        }).toList(),
       )
          ],
        )
        )
        );
      }
```

[image: SS]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think, I needed to know how to loop through the sorted array to access a key, say count for example.