# How can I fetch map data on screen in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase at the backend. I have the data like this in my firebase.
[image]

The fields questions and and question 1 are map, and then I have four string option fields and one answer field. I am extracting the data like this,

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getQuizInfo() async {
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("quizzes")
      .doc('IQfcs1xF6j0ZrRTVDG3b')
      .get();
}

return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
            child: ListTile(
              title: FutureBuilder(
                future: getQuizInfo(),
                builder:
                    (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                     Card(child:Text("Q # 01"+snapshot.data!.data()["questions"]
                        ["question 1"]["description"]));
                        Card(child:Text(snapshot.data!.data()["questions"]
                        ["question 1"]["option 1"]));
                      return Text("Q # 01"+snapshot.data!.data()["questions"]
                        ["question 1"]["description"]+'\n'+"a) "+snapshot.data!.data()["questions"]
                        ["question 1"]["option 1"]+'\n'+"b) "+snapshot.data!.data()["questions"]
                        ["question 1"]["option 2"]+'\n'+"c) "+snapshot.data!.data()["questions"]
                        ["question 1"]["option 3"]+'\n'+"d) "+snapshot.data!.data()["questions"]
                        ["question 1"]["option 4"]);
                  } else if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                      ConnectionState.none) {
                    return Text("No data");
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            )),
      ],
    ));
```

}
}

But that doesn't seem to be an efficient way. Isn't there any way to fetch data as a whole document and load it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to just loop over the `snaopshot` as it is already a map of type `Map<String, dynamic>` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59980717/5519300).

Also instead of generating a big `Text` wigget I would recommend to use a `Column` widget that has multiple `Text` widgets inside to be more flexible.