# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' in a nested JSON

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I have this json from a weather api using Caracas Venezuela as location and I want to get daily_chance_of_rain and daily_will_it_rain:

```
 "forecast": {
    "forecastday": [
        {
            "day": {
                "daily_will_it_rain": 1,
                "daily_chance_of_rain": 97,

 //The Json is longer, so I cropped it
```

I try to get it like this because those values are int:

```
  int? will_it_rain;
  int? chance_of_rain;

  var searchResult = await http
    .get(Uri.parse(searchApiUrl + "Caracas" + "&days=1&aqi=no&alerts=no"));
  var result = json.decode(searchResult.body);

  will_it_rain =
       result["forecast"]["forecastday"]["day"]["daily_will_it_rain"];
  chance_of_rain =
       result["forecast"]["forecastday"]["day"]["daily_chance_of_rain"];
```

But I get:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')
```

Why do I get that error is those values are int not strings?

Comment: This error means that you did this `someList['some string']`, that is to say, you passed a string into an index, in this case, `forecastday` is actually a list of days, so you need to do something like `result["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["day"]["daily_will_it_rain"];`

Comment: Dayum @h8moss it worked, ty <3 :u post that answer if you want some precious points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you did this `someList['some string']`, that is to say, you passed a string into an index, in this case, `forecastday` is actually a list of days, so you need to do something.

```
will_it_rain =
       result["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["day"]["daily_will_it_rain"];
  chance_of_rain =
       result["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["day"]["daily_chance_of_rain"];
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to define index when returning result like this:

```
result["forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["day"]["daily_will_it_rain"];
```

or you can use iterate like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979056/iterate-through-map-values-in-dart-flutter).