# Flutter how to iterate through map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, widget

hey can u help iterate through map and build Text widget every time ?
this is the code i used for filling Map

```
  Map<sectorItems, bool> sectors = {};
  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < sectors.length; i++) {
      sectors = {sectorItems.values[i]: false};
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate through map values in dart / flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979056/iterate-through-map-values-in-dart-flutter)

Comment: `build Text widget every time ? ` does it mean `sectors` is getting update inside widget and can you show the implementation of  `sectors`?

Comment: I get this error The element type 'Set<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.dartlist_element_type_not_assignable

Comment: I think your `sectors = {sectorItems.values[i]: false}` is creating sectors to be a set instead of a map. I think you mean `sectors[sectorItems.values[i]] = false`

Comment: `sectors` is empty,  no effect on loop, Can you include more details

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `sectors` is a `Map`, you can use this code.

```
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    
    for(var key in sectors.values){
      //get string for text widget
      widgets.add(Text(string));
    }
```

This cycles through the keys in your map

```
    for(var key in sectors.values){
       ...
    }
```