# accessing data which is stored inside firebase real time database

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I am getting data in this way from firebase real time database

```
{
  -NCPZuwqiuMwtaKfW-g9: {
    latitude: -122.083922, 
    longitude: 37.4214938
  }, 
  -NCPntX1RFEyzvxYsgBe: {
    latitude: -122.083922, 
    longitude: 37.4214938
  }, 
  -NCPoSmW2MxMnySLDCYg: {
    latitude: -122.07730409759519, 
    longitude: 37.41749643309451
  }, 
  -NCPbS50dJZ_gtlUEK82: {
    latitude: -122.07730527365285, 
    longitude: 37.417498330741125
  },
```

now i want to access the latitude and longitude of the database but i am unable to get it what i tried is this

```
_dbReference
            ?.child("LiveTracker")
            .child("$passedId")
            .onValue
            .listen((event) {
          print("asasdasdasdsaddsadsadsadsadsad${event.snapshot.value}");
          /* _markers.add(Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(DateTime.now().toIso8601String()),
              position: LatLng(double.parse(event.snapshot.value.toString()),
                  double.parse(event.snapshot.value.toString()))));*/
        });
```

i want to listen to the real time data and add that latitude and longitude inside my marker but i am unable to access the latitude and longitude need some guidance

Answer (score 0):

If `LiveTracker` is the node right above the data you shared, and `passedId` is this one of the `-N` keys, you can get the latitude and longitude with:

```
var data = event.snapshot.value; // this is a Map<String, Object>
print(data["longitude");
print(data["latitude");
```

---

**Update**: since you have multiple `-N...` nodes under your `passedId` key, you'll need to loop over the entries in the map to get the individual  longitude and latitude values. For an example of this see [Iterate through map values in dart / flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979056/iterate-through-map-values-in-dart-flutter)

Comment: i have uploaded a picture of how my data is being saved inside real time database and that -N is auto generated id of firebase and passed id is that number 8 and 2 as you can see and  i still cannot access my data your more guidance can be help to me @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: I updated my answer to show that too.